# find the change points except condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, threshold

I have an array

```
[
-670.0790336045966,
 -670.079352863881,
 -664.7769001654013,
 -662.655094599744,
 -662.6557553135007,
 -662.6551031804399,
 -667.966652577584,
 -670.0779722837389,
 -670.0789732042002]
```

.

I want to detect the changes but only 1 time per edge and remove noise as picture [black circle are noises](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUYry.png)

I expect `[1, 3, 5, 7]`. But it showed `[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]`.

I tried:

Python

```
differences = np.abs(np.diff(array_L))

threshold = 1
distance = 1

change_points = np.where((differences > threshold) & (np.arange(len(array_L)-1) % distance == 0))[0] + 1
change_points1 = np.where((differences > threshold) & (np.arange(len(array_L)-1) % distance == 0))[0]
```

Comment: sorry, i edited real data and picture to show what is the noise that i want to remove here.

Comment: How do you define what is an "edge" and what is "noise". What about an array of for instance `[-670, -670, -660, -670, -670]`? Is the `-660` noise or does it establish an edge? Or can edges be only horizontal? How many similar (and within what epsilon) points does it need to create an edge? Too many open questions here to give a useful answer